# Solr8.0.0 search query issue

Tags: solr

I have a field **country**. I need to do a search in which I need to show the search result of a country or some countries last in the search result for eg. for country code BD. What query should I use to get the above result.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please provide a clear description what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to do the opposite - instead of trying to move the documents matching the country further down, boost everything that *doesn't match* the country up:

```
q=(*:* -country:BD)^999
```

This can also be applied as a boost query (`bq`) with the edismax handler.